# How can I make instances of I²C busses concurrently shareable amongst threads, instead of not concurrently as I've coded it?

Tags: rust

I've written this (omitting the closures):

```
use once_cell::sync::Lazy;
use rppal::i2c::{Error, I2c};
use std::{
    collections::HashMap,
    sync::{Arc, Mutex},
};

static GLOBAL_I2C: Lazy<Arc<Mutex<HashMap<u8, I2c>>>> =
    Lazy::new(|| Arc::new(Mutex::new(HashMap::new())));

fn perform_i2c_operation<T, F>(
    bus: u8,
    slave_address: u16,
    operation: F,
) -> Result<T, Error>
where
    F: FnOnce(&mut I2c) -> Result<T, Error>,
{
    // Get the mutex lock for the HashMap
    let mut i2c_map = match GLOBAL_I2C.lock() {
        Ok(i2c_map) => i2c_map,
        Err(e) => {
            return Err(Error::Io(std::io::Error::new(
                std::io::ErrorKind::Other,
                "Not really a thread panic.",
            )));
        }
    };

    // Check if the bus we're interested in is in the map, if not, insert it.
    if !i2c_map.contains_key(&bus) {
        match initialize_i2c(bus) {
            Ok(i2c) => {
                i2c_map.insert(bus, i2c);
            }
            Err(e) => {
                return Err(Error::Io(std::io::Error::new(
                    std::io::ErrorKind::Other,
                    format!("I²C bus couldn't be initialized: {}.", e),
                )));
            }
        }
    }

    // Retrieve the i2c bus instance and perform the operations on it.
    match i2c_map.get_mut(&bus) {
        Some(i2c_instance) => {
            match i2c_instance.set_slave_address(slave_address) {
                Ok(()) => {             
                    operation(i2c_instance)
                }
                Err(e) => Err(e),
            }        
        }
        None => {
            return Err(Error::Io(std::io::Error::new(
                std::io::ErrorKind::Other,
                "I²C bus couldn't be initialized:.")));
        }
    }
}
```

But because of the Mutex around `HashMap`, concurrent accesses to different I²C busses isn't possible.

How would I go about making the different I²C busses be accessed concurrently?

Comment: Nit: The `Arc` is unnecessary.

Comment: You can have `Lazy<RwLock<HashMap<u8, Mutex<I2c>>>>`. Then, concurrent access to the same `I2c` is not possible, but you can you only need write access to the map when you append elements, and all other accesses to different `I2c`s can be concurrent.

Comment: Alternatively, you can initialize all `I2c`s upfront, and then you can have only `Lazy<HashMap<u8, Mutex<I2c>>>`.

Comment: Or use a `Lazy<Mutex<HashMap<u8, Arc<Mutex<I2c>>>>>` so that you don't need to keep the `HashMap` lock while you're using a bus: 1. lock the map, 2. get the bus from the map, 3. clone the bus `Arc`, 4. release the map lock, 5. lock the bus and use it.